# Error en Visual Studio Code no reconoce Git

Tags: git, cmd, vscode

estoy trabajando en un proyecto usando yolov5 en visual studio code. Para instalar yolov5 es necesario clonar un repositorio, cosa que no he tenido problemas puesto que tengo el github desktop, pero al hacer las pruebas básicas en Visual Studio me sale el siguiente error:

```
python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --img 640 --conf 0.25 --source data/images/
Namespace(agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, classes=None, conf_thres=0.25, device='', exist_ok=False, img_size=640, iou_thres=0.45, name='exp', project='runs/detect', save_conf=False, save_txt=False, source='data/images/', update=False, view_img=False, weights=['yolov5s.pt'])
"git" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 175, in <module>
    detect()
  File "detect.py", line 29, in detect
    device = select_device(opt.device)
  File "D:\german\Escritorio\Universidad\TFG\Proyecto\yolov5\utils\torch_utils.py", line 56, in select_device
    s = f'YOLOv5 {git_describe()} torch {torch.__version__} '  # string
  File "D:\german\Escritorio\Universidad\TFG\Proyecto\yolov5\utils\torch_utils.py", line 49, in git_describe
    return subprocess.check_output('git describe --tags --long --always', shell=True).decode('utf-8')[:-1]
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\TFG\lib\subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\TFG\lib\subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git describe --tags --long --always' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Haciendo pruebas, he descubierto que la terminal de visual studio, no me reconoce Git. Sin embargo, la cmd básica de Windows, si me la reconoce (código más abajo) y el propio Visual Studio también reconoce el git en el apartado de "Source Control".

```
git --version
git version 2.30.1.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono volviendo a instalarlo y en la opción de "Choosing the default editor used by Git", elegir la opción de:

```
Use visual Studio Code as Git´s default Editor
```

Luego continuar con la instalación normal y listo